# trying to update a table

Tags: mysql

I have altered a table and added a new column and then trying to insert into the column by using update query but I am gettig error can you guys please help me.

Here is my code

```sql
DECLARE @cnt5 INT = 0;
   WHILE @cnt5 < 3
   BEGIN
   DECLARE @colname NVARCHAR(MAX)='ApporveCosting-S'+cast(@cnt5+1 as nvarchar(max))
   exec ('ALTER TABLE #TempResult ADD ['+ @colname +'] NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL')
   exec ('update #TempResult set ['+ @colname+']') =(  select  (select case  (select count(*) from (select  top (@cnt5+1)   EA.EntityAssociationId, ISNULL(KD.ActualDate,KD.CurrentDate) AS ExpOrActDate
FROM EntityAssociations EA 
    INNER JOIN dbo.EntityMasterData emd ON emd.EntityMasterDataId = EA.EntityMasterDataId
    INNER JOIN zInquiryStageLookup ISL on ISL.InquiryStageId = EA.StageId
    INNER JOIN KeyDates KD ON KD.KeyDateId = EA.AssociatedInstanceId AND EA.AssociatedEntityTypeId=27
    Where 
        EA.EntityInstanceId = #temp.CustomerInquiryId
        AND (EA.StageId = 2)
        AND KD.IsActive = 1
        AND EMD.EntityMasterDataId < 1000
        AND (ISNULL(KD.isOnlyDashboardVisible, 0) = 0)
        and KD.KeyDateName='Approve Costing' order by EA.EntityAssociationId asc)b) when (@cnt5+1) then (select top 1 ExpOrActDate FROM  (select  top (@cnt5+1)   EA.EntityAssociationId, ISNULL(KD.ActualDate,KD.CurrentDate) AS ExpOrActDate
FROM EntityAssociations EA 
    INNER JOIN dbo.EntityMasterData emd ON emd.EntityMasterDataId = EA.EntityMasterDataId
    INNER JOIN zInquiryStageLookup ISL on ISL.InquiryStageId = EA.StageId
    INNER JOIN KeyDates KD ON KD.KeyDateId = EA.AssociatedInstanceId AND EA.AssociatedEntityTypeId=27
    Where 
        EA.EntityInstanceId = #temp.CustomerInquiryId 
        AND (EA.StageId = 2)
        AND KD.IsActive = 1
        AND EMD.EntityMasterDataId < 1000
        AND (ISNULL(KD.isOnlyDashboardVisible, 0) = 0)
        and KD.KeyDateName='Approve Costing' order by EA.EntityAssociationId asc)a order by EntityAssociationId desc) else null end) from #tempresult #temp where #temp.CustomerInquiryId=#tempresult.CustomerInquiryId)

   SET @cnt5 = @cnt5 + 1;
   END;
```

Thank You.

Comment: The code is specific for SQL Server (aka MS SQL). Why it is [mysql]-tagged?

Comment: ^What Akina said. What database system, version, and edition are you using? Please show the rest of the code where the temp table `#TempResult` gets created.

Comment: If you ask for help with an error, please include the exact error text in your question.

Comment: What's the error message?  Can't you do it in a single `UPDATE` with a `JOIN` instead of looping in a Stored Procedure?